# Qt error after switch to ITK 4

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, itk

We have a Windows7 VS2008 C++ app that uses both ITK 3.10.1 and Qt 4.5. We run CMake 2.6-patch 4 to generate both ITK and our app C++ projects, and everything run OK.
Now I switch to ITK 4.1.0, and to do this I had to upgrade CMake from 2.6 to 2.8 and generate ITK 4.5 and our app with this CMake. Now ITK compiles OK, but the app does not. The error dialog reads "There is no Qt version assigned to this project for platform Win32. Please use the 'change Qt version' feature and choose a valid Qt version for this platform.".
The platform was Win32 and still is; the computer is the same, and I did not touch Qt. Obviously I did not do something that should be done or did something that should not.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Mike

Comment: That looks like the error message you get in the Visual Studio Qt addin. If so just click Qt on the Visual Studio menu and then navigate to Qt Options and add your Qt version.

Comment: Dear @drescherjm, thanks a lot! I have just one qt version, it worked OK but now it does not... Should I create a new qt version?

Comment: Does the selected version in the Qt addin exist?